# Where to find the jars to include in jogl 2.0?

Tags: java, jogl, configuration-management

I'm trying to make this example work, just to make sure I got my environment set up:
[Using_JOGL_in_a_Java_applet](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Using_JOGL_in_a_Java_applet)

Then I downloaded either jogl or jogamp, the name seems to be used interchangeably
[Instructions on downloading jogl](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_JOGL)

I downloaded the all platforms version, since I'm developing on multiple platforms
[jogamp-all-platforms.7z](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-current/archive/)

Then I tried to compile the example code with -classpath jogamp-all-platforms/jar/*
But it doesn't find any of the jogl packages.

There are so many versions of jogl, and so many jars, but no comprehensive step by step tutorial for setting this thing up. Why doesn't it find the packages, the jar files are all in the jogamp-all-platforms/jar/ folder?

Comment: which java version you are using

Comment: As a warning, insulting people attempting to help you out is not acceptable here. I've removed the offending comment, but please refrain from doing this again.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add the gluegen-rt.jar and jogl-all.jar when you compile and run a JogAmp jogl applications. All the native jars only needs to be located next to these two jars.

Its not possible to use a wildcard * because the jars needs to be separated by a : when adding jars to the classpath on the commandline.

Linux/Unix users use

```
-classpath jogamp-all-platforms/jar/jogl-all.jar:jogamp-all-platforms/jar/gluegen-rt.jar
```

Windows users use

```
-classpath jogamp-all-platforms\jar\jogl-all.jar;jogamp-all-platforms\jar\gluegen-rt.jar
```

For more detailed information see the JogAmp FAQ that also covers how to compile on the commandline:
http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE